# CSS to modify text only in a hyperlink with image and text

Tags: css

I have an example jquery menu item that looks like this:

```
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
     <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/alligator-black_20.jpeg">
        Alligator Black
     </a>
    </li>
```

All I'm trying to do is format the text ("Alligator Black") only without affecting the img too. There are many menu items, so the text would change depending on the search results.

I can't easily modify the jquery code, so I'm hoping there is a CSS only solution?

As you can probably guess, Alligator Black is crammed against the image and I simply want to add some left padding and bottom padding to center it a little more.

Any help is always appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add your margin or padding to the <img> which you can select with CSS?

Comment: I was going to mention that as a worst case scenario, but forgot. The text sits at the bottom of the image which is probably twice as tall as the text...so it looks a little bad. But, I'll definitely add the margin if that's my only option. Thanks. ... Also, I've tried text-align and it doesn't seem to affect anything... So, if I could get that to work with the margin...that would be totally acceptable.

Comment: You can work with negative margins, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify the image styles to achieve your desired result:

```
.ui-menu-item img {
    margin-right: 1em; // To space it out

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Play around with the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) values to position the image in a way that makes the text look centred. You can also use `vertical-align` in conjunction with `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` for greater control.

Of course this may not work if the text spans multiple lines.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. My hosting provider was upgrading the network at exactly that moment... Anyway, that works great. Vertical-align is what I meant in my comment above that didn't affect anything (even though I tried text-align as well and several other things). I guess vertical-align requires the display property? I need to get a better grasp on the display property as I just used inline-flex to fix a alignment issue and I don't really understand why it works. I bet this solution would fix that issue too... Many thanks!

Comment: Vertical align is one of quirkiest CSS properties. If I'm not mistaken, it only works on inline-block items and table cells and they mean different things. [This article describes it well.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/). If you are able to use flexbox then I would suggest using it instead as it is much more powerful.

Comment: Excellent, I've seen flexbox code here and there, but haven't really grasped what the underlying mechanism is yet. I'll definitely check it out as well as that link. Thanks again!